# How to set properties dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am setting the array for a series of views with the following code. bunnyView1 through bunnyView7 are instances of UIImageView created in the storyboard but I want to automate the process so I can generate the connections with code. How would I set the values inside a loop?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
NSMutableArray *hopAnimation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    [hopAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame-%i.png", i]]];
}
self.bunnyView1.animationImages=hopAnimation;
self.bunnyView2.animationImages=hopAnimation;
self.bunnyView3.animationImages=hopAnimation;
self.bunnyView4.animationImages=hopAnimation;
self.bunnyView5.animationImages=hopAnimation;
self.bunnyView6.animationImages=hopAnimation;
self.bunnyView7.animationImages=hopAnimation;
self.bunnyView1.animationDuration=1;
self.bunnyView2.animationDuration=1;
self.bunnyView3.animationDuration=1;
self.bunnyView4.animationDuration=1;
self.bunnyView5.animationDuration=1;
self.bunnyView6.animationDuration=1;
self.bunnyView7.animationDuration=1;                             
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Comment: please elaborate , wahat would one infer when there's no datatype ,no class ..please share more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your variables in an Array. And iterate the array and set values . For ex,

```
NSArray *collection = [[NSArray    alloc]initWithObjects:@"object1",@"object2",@"object3",@"object4",nil];
```

Comment: I understand how to add the items to an array, but how about the situation where you have a large number of objects (i.e. n objects).

Comment: My intention was not to tell how to add things to array. To iterate in  members you can put them in array to iterate. If you have large number of similar members create array of such objects(I am not talking about putting it in NSArray).

Answer (score 1):

You should use an IBOutletCollection of UIImageView which every bunnyView should be linked to. Declaration goes like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray * bunnyViews;
```